# xcode 8 simulator goes white and then black

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

The simulator that I'm using turns white for a second then turns to black and I no sure what the cause of this is. I have already updated everything so that's not the problem.

this is all my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

As you can see in the code I have a button in my app and when I run the code the simulator seems to be working at first, but then turns black and stays black

I have a mid 2012 MacBook Pro

I already:

-Restarted my computer

-Reset Content and Settings

Attached are screenshots of when I run the debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lub3a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sySNM.png)

Comment: do you see any logs in debugger?

Comment: you need to edit your question to include those images... we can't see images in the comments

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog how do I do that I? This is my first time in Stack overflow so I don't know how to do a lot of things on here.

Comment: Underneath the question there are three options "Share" "Edit" "Flag"... Click the "edit" button and add those two images just like you added the image of the black screen

Comment: Okay, I added screenshots of when I run the debugger. Let me know if you need me to add any more as I can only have 2 pictures per question @MSU_Bulldog

Comment: You need to post the error messages from the console.  The console is the area on the bottom right of Xcode where it says "(lldb)" in blue.  Scroll up in that area and there will be an error message that tells you why the app crashed

Comment: Okay, I added a screenshot of the 11db console @MSU_Bulldog

Answer (score 1):

This behavior sounds like you don't have a root/initial view controller. Go to your storyboard and make sure that there is an arrow pointing to your view controller and make sure that view controller is linked to the correct class. In your case, the view controller should be set to ViewController.

[image: Storyboard showing initial view controller]

[image]

Comment: I just check view controller and I have mine set up the same way as the pictures you share so I not sure that's the problem.

Comment: @AndreaG. Have you made any changes in the app delegate?

Comment: What happens if you open up a new project and try to run it?

Comment: I did that twice and the same problem keeps happening @Kilo Loco

Comment: This is really weird! I'm sorry I haven't been helpful. What version of Xcode are you running? The fact that you have a 2012 computer shouldn't matter. I have a 2009 MacBook Pro and it still works...